# I'm trying to read in class pointers to a vector with a for loop, but it only works if I declare object inside loop

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

So my code only works when I read in the data in the loop with the shape pointer variable declared inside it.

```
std::vector<shape*> objList; 
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        shape* sphere = new Sphere(keskitalo::Vec3D(0,0,-10), 0.5); 
        sphere->setCenter(keskitalo::Vec3D(i - 5, i - 5, -10));
        objList.push_back(sphere);
    }
```

I feel like this isn't the best practice, and I want to declare it like this.

```
std::vector<shape*> objList; 
shape* sphere = new Sphere(keskitalo::Vec3D(0,0,-10), 0.5); 
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        sphere->setCenter(keskitalo::Vec3D(i - 5, i - 5, -10));
        objList.push_back(sphere);
    }
```

When I use this bottom set of code the whole vector gets set to the last iteration of the for loop, and it doesn't make any sense. Everything gets set to [4,4,-10]

Here is the code for all the functions I use. Also, the Vec3D variable is just a vector of size three.

```
void shape::setCenter(keskitalo::Vec3D center){    //in shape class
    m_center = center;
}

Sphere::Sphere(keskitalo::Vec3D center, double radius)  //constructor for sphere class.
        :m_center(center),
         m_radius(radius){}
```

Idk if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: *"I feel like this isn't the best practice, and I want to declare it like this."* - then you get exactly what you asked for, a vector of 10 copies of the same *pointer value*, the last rendition of `setCenter` shared by all, because in fact there is only *ONE* object and ten copies of a single pointer value referring to said-object. Whatever possessed you to think, "I feel this isn't the best practice" needs a reality check with how C++ works....

Answer (score 1):

`objList` is a list of pointers. The value you're appending to `objList` is a pointer to a sphere, and while you do change the value of that sphere, the value you're pushing the list isn't a copy of the underlying sphere object, it's a copy of the sphere object's address. The address remains unchanged, so what you end up with is a list of 10 pointers, all pointing to the same sphere object in memory, which was last modified by the final iteration of the `for` loop.

If your vector must be of type `shape*` and not `shape`, then there is no reason not to use the first method. In this case, you create a new sphere every iteration, just like you need to.